# Windows azure redis cache migration issue

Tags: azure, lucene, redis-cache

We are hosting our site on windows azure where site is running on multiple instances.Due to multiple instances we were using shared cache for storing session values. As Microsoft is going to stop shared cache and recommended to use redis cache to store session. I modified project to use redis cache and it worked for most of the pages. My problem is that, we have a  very important page "search page" (we are using lucene.net for search functionality) in our site which stores a lot of data in session and this page is not working. After hitting search button, it shows connecting status in address bar for a long time and goes to oops page of website. We are recording error messages in DB so after looking at there we found following error message.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'myWeb.clsSearchCriteria+ContentCriteria' in Assembly 'HelmBriscoeWeb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisUtility.GetBytesFromObject(Object data)
   at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisUtility.AppendUpdatedOrNewItemsInList(ChangeTrackingSessionStateItemCollection sessionItems, List`1 list)
   at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryUpdateIfLockIdMatchPrepare(Object lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection data, Int32 sessionTimeout, String[]& keyArgs, Object[]& valueArgs)
   at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryUpdateIfLockIdMatch(Object lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection data, Int32 sessionTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnEndRequest(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I am not sure if this is related to my problem but seems if this is fixed, page will work properly. Has anyone any idea why this error occurred and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself by adding serialization attribute to class like below.

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class clsSearchCriteria
```

Thanks